# Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path. Node j.s install canvas issue

Tags: node.js, canvas, terminal, cairo

I am having a problem installing installing the canvas module in node..It seems to be something with cairo I am getting this error...

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/canvas
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

> canvas@1.1.3 install /Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'cairo' found
gyp: Call to './util/has_cairo_freetype.sh' returned exit status 0. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:424:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 13.0.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/plimb/Desktop/motion-therapy/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.21
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.10
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! weird error 1 
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm not sure what it all means! Would appreciate any help!For example how to a mkdir cairo pc in the pkg_config_path environment variable?

Comment: See if this helps out: https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/225

Comment: ah thanks ken, I followed this but now I have this error   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
In file included from ../src/Canvas.cc:7:
../src/Canvas.h:19:10: fatal error: 'cairo/cairo.h' file not found
#include <cairo/cairo.h>

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Had the same problem and **@Epistemex's [link](https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/225) helped me troubleshoot it.**

> *... You need to install `libcairo2-dev`, `libjpeg-dev` and `libgif-dev` packages ...*

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev
```

Comment: I also needed the pangocairo package, resolved with `sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev`

Comment: This wont work in amzon ec2 instance, as they are not debian? any one know yum command for this

Comment: `cairo-devel` `libjpeg-devel` and `giflib-devel` are the Amazon Linux packages. @Max

Comment: @AdlenAfane comment is really relevant for those wanting install `manim`.

Answer (score 72):

I was also facing same issue on mac 
so I have tried these steps & I got solution

Mac OSX Version >=10.7.5
node -v = v0.8.12

```
$ brew install cairo
$ pkg-config --atleast-version=1.12.2 cairo
$ echo $?
```

If it returns a 1 you will need to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable so cairo.pc and fontconfig.pc can be found

```
$ locate cairo.pc
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig/
```

Running pkg-config again ...

```
$ pkg-config --atleast-version=1.12.2 cairo

$ echo $?
```

If it returns a 0 then all is well in the hood.

```
$ npm install canvas
```

Comment: Appreciate the details. Good one.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers using Mac/brew.

On Mac, if you're using `macports`, this worked for me:

    $ sudo port install cairo
    $ sudo port install pkgconfig # not sure this one is mandatory... :/
    $ npm install canvas

Comment: What if it continues to return 1 after running `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/`?

Answer (score 32):

Had the same problem on OS X 10.11.2 while installing `qrcode` package.

Solved by installing these ones:

```
brew install cairo
brew install pkg-config
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Only `brew install cairo` was sufficient in my case (macOS Sierra 10.12.1)

Comment: with a brand-new installation of macOS Sierra 10.12 (Recovered), `brew install cairo` should be enough, just confirmed.

Comment: it looks like `brew install cairo` automatically install `pkg-config` as well

Answer (score 15):

If anyone is still having this problem and found this page, the following works for CentOS 6.6:

```
sudo yum install cairo cairo-devel
```

Basically the solution is you need to install the development package as well as the regular package (the best answer here does the same thing - except is for Ubuntu - every distro can be different).

Answer (score 9):

I followed the steps given by @Piyush. But I needed an extra step to make it work. I'm using OS X 10.14.5

So this is what I followed.

```js
brew install pkg-config
brew install cairo
pkg-config --atleast-version=1.12.2 cairo
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/X11/lib/pkgconfig/
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
npm install canvas
```

Answer (score 6):

For Ubuntu, these're the commands. Also, here's the [reference](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation:-Ubuntu-and-other-Debian-based-systems).

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this on mac:

```
brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! Running a m2 macbook air with OSX 12.6, node v18.12.1, and npm 8.19.3

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is just fine if you use apt-get.  For YUM/DNF users (Fedora, CentOS, other RHEL-like systems), use the following

```
yum install cairo cairo-devel cairomm-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel pango pango-devel pangomm pangomm-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into this problem the issue was that the version of `pkg-config` on my path was the version supplied by chefdk instead of the homebrew installed version.

```
$ which pkg-config
/usr/local/bin/pkg-config

$ eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"
$ which pkg-config
/opt/chefdk/embedded/bin/pkg-config
```

The solution was to remove the `eval "$(chef shell-init bash)"` entry from my bash profile.

More discussion of the issue in chefdk's path generation on Github https://github.com/chef/chef-dk/issues/313

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to install pkg-config on OSX 10.10.4

`brew install pkg-config`