# Canvas for Node.js working locally but not on Heroku server

Tags: node.js, canvas, heroku

I am using the [canvas package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) for Node.js.

It works fine on my computer, but it does not work when I upload it to my Heroku server. By "works fine", I mean that the canvas package correctly installed with `npm install canvas` and the Node.js application works as expected.

However, when I try and upload it to Heroku and it tries to build the canvas package, I get the error:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 4304, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4028/4028), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4304/4304), 3.57 MiB | 606.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4304 (delta 737), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  5.6.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   3.7.2
remote:
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.6.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing npm 3.7.2 (replacing version 3.6.0)...
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
remote:
remote:        > canvas@1.3.10 install /tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/node_modules/canvas
remote:        > node-gyp rebuild
remote:
remote:        make: Entering directory `/tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/node_modules/canvas/build'
remote:        SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
remote:        COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasGradient.o
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o
remote:        In file included from ../src/CanvasPattern.cc:9:0:
remote:        ../src/Image.h:19:21: fatal error: gif_lib.h: No such file or directory
remote:        #include <gif_lib.h>
remote:        ^
remote:        compilation terminated.

remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory `/tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/node_modules/canvas/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_module
s/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/.h
eroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/node_modules/canvas
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-71-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/.hero
ku/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
remote:        npm ERR! node v5.6.0
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.7.2
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! canvas@1.3.10 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.3.10 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild

remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs canvas
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_565c08c270a791191b278953392f5493/npm-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:
remote:        - node_modules checked into source control
remote:        https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git

remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to colladraw.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/colladraw.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/colladraw.git'
```

The error is specifically in these lines:

```
In file included from ../src/CanvasPattern.cc:9:0:
remote:        ../src/Image.h:19:21: fatal error: gif_lib.h: No such file or directory
remote:        #include <gif_lib.h>

remote:        ^
remote:        compilation terminated.
```

These problems do not exist on my system, however. I fiddled around with solutions from other questions regarding this issue, such as [this question](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/225) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100213/package-cairo-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path-node-j-s-install-canv). The problem is that both of these are for the local machines, and they do not get pushed to the server, and therefore I could not fix the problem on Heroku.

**Possible Solution 1**

It looks as though Heroku is trying to re-build all of the packages on its own according to these lines:

```
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
remote:        Rebuilding any native modules
```

I would guess that if it doesn't re-build `node_modules` and just uses the one from my computer (that is working), then it would also work on the server. Is there any way to stop it from automatically re-building?

**Possible Solution 2**

Heroku allows you to run [one-off dynos](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dynos), such as `heroku run bash`. This opens a bash client connected to the server.

I was thinking that maybe I could perform the solutions from the other questions regarding this issue directly on the Heroku server. However, they are very restrictive and do not allow `sudo` access nor `apt-get install`. Is there any way to circumvent this?

Feel free to provide additional ideas. Thanks for any solutions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40310421/3310334

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node-canvas depends on [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/), a graphics library written in C. Cairo must be installed on whatever server you are trying to deploy to.

If you want to deploy to Heroku, you'll likely have to use a custom build pack. There is example documentation for how to do that here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation-on-Heroku

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I didn't see this article. Thanks!

Comment: Recommendation: do not use the multipack repository in that Node-Canvas wiki page. You can use the official Heroku multipack instead: `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git`. See instructions here: https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi#buildpack-instructions

Comment: I'm getting this `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format` after add cairo buildpack