# Adjusting width of tables made with kable() in RMarkdown documents

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Is it possible to adjust the width of columns when making tables with the kable() function in knitr?

A chunk like this for a table with two columns produces a table that takes up the entire width of the document.  I'd like to make the columns narrower.  **Can this be done with kable() or is another package needed?**

This rmarkdown chunk

````
```{r}
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
           y = 11:20)
library(knitr)
kable(df)
```
````

Produces this table
[image]

Aligning left with `kable(df, align = "l")` helps a little but I'd like the two columns adjacent to each other.

Comment: I am not able to replicate with default Rstudio .Rmd file, outputting PDF.

Comment: Try `knitr::kable(x, format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:30%;'")` from (https://twitter.com/vrnijs/status/599275956247789568)

Comment: @MarBlo that's worth an answer.

Answer (score 47):

You can try out the `kableExtra` package.

```
kable(x, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me because it seems that kable_styling does not support document formats provided you use libre office it doesnt work no. i do not know how microsoft office would handle the output though

Comment: @hao: I am having difficulties to adjust the width in a kableExtra table, which should also include an image, please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58204272/r-markdown-how-to-create-a-table-with-images-and-text-which-should-be-knitted-a
Would you have any advice?

Comment: @Hao great package!   I would add this additional part to control the width exactly as you want it. `kable(x, table.attr = "style='width:40%;'" ) %>% kable_classic(full_width = T, position = "center", )`

Comment: This restricts the width of the caption to the width of the resulting table. It would be nice if the two could be decoupled.

Answer (score 20):

My new favorite thing is the `flextable` package because 1) the tables are beautiful, 2) you can more easily control things like width and font size, and 3) they render well to HTML *and* Word. Using your data:

````
```{r}
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
df %>% regulartable() %>% autofit() %>% 
width(j=~x,width=1) %>% width(j=~y,width=1)
```
````

With both values of `width` set to 1, the columns are close together:

[image: flextable-1]

If you adjust the last line to `width(j=~x,width=2) %>% width(j=~y,width=2)` the table looks like this:

[image: flextable-2]

Comment: According to the [flextable overview vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/overview.html), you can also use `df %>% flextable() %>% autofit()`. In case you have an issue installing flextable, make sure you have the libcairo dependency installed at a system level as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23649012/2641825) `sudo apt install libcairo2-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev`.

Answer (score 20):

I know it is a long time since my comment. But as @Tjebo pointed out, my comment is worth an answer, I wanted follow his advise.
By defining the table format and adding some CSS styling you can change the size of the like so: `knitr::kable(x, format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:30%;'")`.
This may lead to loosing the table lines. **kableExtra** offer nice styling tools to add for instance lines.

```
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)

kable(df, format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:30%;'")

kable(df, format = "html", table.attr = "style='width:30%;'") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

Comment: @Nbrouwer maybe worth considering to accept this answer?

Comment: Note that the explicit `format = "html"` is required. It doesn't work if you leave the default and knit to html

Answer (score 2):

I am new to R but possibly my answer will be useful to other newbies here. Experts, please feel free to correct.

I had a similar issue as the original poster: using kable() my table was off the page and I wanted to rescale. I tried the other answers posted and didn't have success, the reasons may have been that I didn't (at all or properly) install kableExtra or magrittr (the package that allows you to use %>%).

Ultimately, I ended up using latex_options="scale_down", see below:

```
endpoints <- read.delim("D:/RFiles/GenericName/Endpoints.txt",
            header=TRUE, sep="\t", dec=".")
endpoints_table <- knitr::kable(endpoints,col.names=gsub(" 
                   [.]"," ",names(endpoints)), align="l", 
                   caption = "Endpoints Available")
kable_styling(endpoints_table,latex_options="scale_down",
              "striped") %>%
  row_spec(0,bold=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to fit the table with kableExtra (for me all other optionsdidn't work) package is to use kable_paper( full_width = F)

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)    
kbl(dt) %>% kable_paper(full_width = F)
```

Comment: works but applies an entire set of styling include a narrow font: 

`html_font = "\"Arial Narrow\", arial, helvetica, sans-serif"`

Comment: then you can use kable_classic from the same package like kable_classic(full_width = F, html_font = "Cambria") (or any other required font)