# Reduce spacing between columns in table created with kable(, format = 'markdown')

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I try to create a table using the format "markdown" of the function *kable()*, but the spaces between the columns are so wide that the table extends over the page. Is there anyway to adjust the cell size so that a table in markdown format does not extend over the page? In *latex* format it stays within the page, but I do not want this format nor do I want *html*. I want the output file to be .pdf. 
I know that a similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900335/adjusting-width-of-tables-made-with-kable-in-rmarkdown-documents), but my question is specific to the format *markdown*. If you feel this is a duplicate, please merge the questions.

Reproducible example:

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "JAQuent"
date: "7 Juni 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

\tiny

```{r results='asis', echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(knitr)

table1 <- data.frame(Factor1 = c('level 1', 'level 1', 'level 2', 'level 2'),
                     Factor2 = c('level 1', 'level 2', 'level 1', 'level 2'),
                     Parameter1 = sample(1000000:9999999, 2),
                     Parameter2 = sample(1000000:9999999, 2),
                     Parameter3 = sample(1000000:9999999, 2),
                     Parameter4 = sample(1000000:9999999, 2),
                     Parameter5 = sample(1000000:9999999, 2),
                     Parameter6 = sample(1000000:9999999, 2),
                     Parameter7 = sample(1000000:9999999, 2))

names(table1) <- c('Factor1', 'Factor2', 'Parameter1', 'Parameter2', 'Parameter3', 'Parameter4', 'Parameter5', 'Parameter6', 'Parameter7')


kable(table1, format = 'markdown')
kable(table1, format = 'latex')
```
````

[image]

Comment: Just using `kable(table1)` actually gives a fitting table for me (removing the format argument)

Comment: Your solution combined with using \tiny works perfectly.

Comment: [For Hao's answer, see for specifics on using kableExtra package.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56254631/table-way-too-wide-to-fit-in-markdown-generated-pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of the examples in `?kable` contain a padding argument. Feeding it `0L` gets you closer, but it turns out that this argument will take negative integers, so

```
kable(table1, format = 'markdown', padding=-1L)
```

will produce something closer to what your are looking for.

Comment: Although the OP did ask for the markdown format, it's worth noting that the padding argument is not useable with the latex format

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is actually `kable(table, "latex", booktabs = T)`. Also, you can check out the [`kableExtra`](http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/) package which makes it easy to modify the kable outputs.