# R Markdown Table Sizing Inconsistent

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

When I output my R Markdown (knitr / RStudio) to html the following table stretches the full width of the browser you view it in. It's only two columns and looks rather odd stretched out on a widescreen display.

```
Col1 | Col2
--- | ---
1 | 1
1349 | 143910
```

This same table shown below, same syntax, correctly limits the width of Column 1 to the width of its own contents. The only difference is the cell contents of position [2, 2] are extremely long.

```
Col1 | Col2
--- | ---
1 | 1
1349 | 143910143910143910143910143910143910143910143910143910
```

How do I force knitr or pandoc or R or whatever to limit column width to only slightly larger than the columns contents. Why did the extreme number of characters in cell [2, 2] force my output to behave as I wish? I didn't involve any CSS in the second table and prefer not to mess around with CSS.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41900335/5784831)

Comment: use e.g. grid tables, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables (or use CSS)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `kable` from the `knitr` package and `kable_styling` from the `kableExtra` package.

Supposing your dataframe is `df`

```
kable(df, "html") %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

You can find more info here.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kableExtra/versions/0.6.1/topics/kable_styling

EDIT: eipi10´S clarifications on packages. (Thanks!)