# How to increase the width of the table output in RStudio Notebook visual markdown editor

Tags: rstudio, rnotebook

I'm trying to use a notebook in RStudio for an interactive demonstration for students. I like the visual markdown editor, but I'm struggling to format the output.

I can't figure out why the width of the output table is not 100%. It looks fine in the source editor, but not in the visual editor, see screenshots.

[image: visual editor]

[image: source editor]

How can I increase the width of the table in the output? (Note: I mean in the dynamic output that shows up immediately after running the code, not in the knitted document or the automatically saved nb.html file.) I tried setting fig.width, width, table.width in the chunk options, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: What version of RStudio are you using? What you're describing sounds like this bug: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8531 -- which we don't have a reproducible case for but would welcome one!

Comment: RStudio version is 1.4.1103. I will try updating it, should've thought of that. It is exactly like the bug you mentioned, but I also wasn't able to reliably reproduce it, it worked fine one minute then suddenly it didn't and I'm not sure what caused it. I will let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: @Jonathan do you have any suggestion for a workaround to enable pretty tables in visual mode?

Answer (score -1):

The kable() package does a good job of solving such problems. There is already [a topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900335/adjusting-width-of-tables-made-with-kable-in-rmarkdown-documents) on this topic with lots of code examples.