# Chartjs-node with canvas-prebuilt is still throwing 'Cairo not found' errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, chart.js

I'm currently using `chartjs-node` to generate some charts. My node.js code runs perfectly on my local (windows) machine, but I suspect that's because I have `windows-build-tools` installed, which includes the `cairo` package.

When I push to my remote (linux) server and try to compile, I get the following error:

```
No package 'cairo' found
```

However, my package dependency list is as follows:

```
"canvas-prebuilt": "^1.6.5-prerelease.1",
"chart.js": "2.6.0",
"chartjs-node": "^1.6.1"
```

Based on my understanding from [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-prebuilt), using `canvas-prebuilt` instead of `canvas` should circumvent the need for any package pre-installation on my server. Obviously, I *could* just preinstall the necessary packages ([as described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100213/package-cairo-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path-node-j-s-install-canv)) - but I'm wondering if there's any way to set up my package dependency list to avoid that route.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could switch `chartjs-node` to my [chartjs-node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas) package. It uses `canvas-prebuilt` instead of `canvas`, one of the main reasons for its existance :)

Comment: Aha! I wish I had seen this earlier; I ended up just switching to using [node-highcharts-exporting](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-highcharts-exporting), which has a bit uglier charts, but at least is completely prebuilt. But thanks for the response!