# Can't Install Node Canvas On CentOS 7

Tags: node.js, canvas, npm

Please see attached file which has the command i ran and all the errors output. Does anyone know what is happening and why i can't seem to install Node Canvas?

I did run the command with --unsafe-perm because for some reason it kept saying the root user didn't have permission to write the dev folder?

**LINK TO OUTPUT:**

[CLICK HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rKDUy1P7N5POhnzGEKG8CAbngM3KRfox)

Comment: i see an error `package cairo not found`. so please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100213/package-cairo-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path-node-j-s-install-canv

Comment: According to yum that package is installed Package cairo-1.14.8-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package cairo-devel-1.14.8-2.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version