# Package 'cairo', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Tags: node.js, alpine-linux

I'm using alpine linux within my containers.  A while back I had the same error as [Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path. Node j.s install canvas issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100213/package-cairo-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path-node-j-s-install-canv) I added the following snippet to my Dockerfile:

```
    # Install cairo for one of our frontend dependencies
RUN apk add --update --no-cache cairo \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

This made the error go away (at least according to my memory, it's been a few months).

Today this error popped up again when running `docker-compose exec web yarn watch`.  Here's the full output of the error:

```
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "node-gyp@3.8.0" with binaries:
[1/2] ⠠ canvas
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/var/www/html/node_modules/canvas: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node-gyp rebuild
Arguments: 
Directory: /var/www/html/node_modules/canvas
Output:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.14.0 | linux | x64
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.14.0/node-v8.14.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.14.0/node-v8.14.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.14.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.14.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python2
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/var/www/html/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/root/.node-gyp/8.14.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/root/.node-gyp/8.14.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/root/.node-gyp/8.14.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/var/www/html/node_modules/canvas',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'cairo', required by 'virtual:world', not found
gyp: Call to './util/has_lib.sh freetype' returned exit status 0 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.9.125-linuxkit
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/bin/node-gyp\" \"rebuild\"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/html/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v8.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok"
Done in 98.27s.
```

I can prove Cairo is on the container:

```
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.adfa7ceb.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.efaa1f73.tar.gz: No such file or directory
cairo-1.14.12-r2 description:
A vector graphics library

cairo-1.14.12-r2 webpage:
http://cairographics.org/

cairo-1.14.12-r2 installed size:
1097728

cairo-1.14.12-r2 depends on:
so:libX11.so.6
so:libXext.so.6
so:libXrender.so.1
so:libc.musl-x86_64.so.1
so:libfontconfig.so.1
so:libfreetype.so.6
so:libpixman-1.so.0
so:libpng16.so.16
so:libxcb-render.so.0
so:libxcb-shm.so.0
so:libxcb.so.1
so:libz.so.1

cairo-1.14.12-r2 provides:
so:libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2=2.11400.12
so:libcairo.so.2=2.11400.12

cairo-1.14.12-r2 is required by:

cairo-1.14.12-r2 contains:
usr/lib/libcairo.so.2.11400.12
usr/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2
usr/lib/libcairo-script-interpreter.so.2.11400.12
usr/lib/libcairo.so.2
usr/lib/cairo/cairo-sphinx.so.0
usr/lib/cairo/cairo-fdr.so.0
usr/lib/cairo/cairo-fdr.so
usr/lib/cairo/cairo-fdr.so.0.0.0
usr/lib/cairo/cairo-sphinx.so
usr/lib/cairo/cairo-sphinx.so.0.0.0

cairo-1.14.12-r2 triggers:

cairo-1.14.12-r2 has auto-install rule:

cairo-1.14.12-r2 affects auto-installation of:

cairo-1.14.12-r2 replaces:

cairo-1.14.12-r2 license:
LGPL-2.0-or-later MPL-1.1
```

I don't see any `cairo.pc` file anywhere after some browsing, so how can I determine what step I need to take to educate my `yarn install` on the location of cairo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be easily fixed by installing the `cairo-dev` package.

According to Alpine's package search, it will install `cairo.pc` under `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`, which is likely to be detected by `gyp`:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=cairo.pc&path=&name=&branch=v3.8

Comment: Switching to `cairo-dev` now it wants `make` and everything that goes along with that.   I can do that, but would prefer to keep it light.  Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Needless to say though, this does work, thank you!  I didn't realize I could search for the filename on the alpine package repo

Comment: Sure, @Webnet! Glad to help. For keeping the container as light as possible, you could remove unneeded files, but this will require manual labour. One option is, keeping only the files installed directly by `cairo-dev` (https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=v3.8&name=cairo-dev&arch=x86_64&repo=main), and manually copying only them to the container - then try to build. Cairo headers may depend on other package headers, so you may have to add files gradually, until the build is successful. You could also go the other way - removing files gradually, as long as the build works.

Comment: If there's an `apk` option for ignoring dependencies and installing only the explicitly required package, similar to `apt`'s `-` flag (https://serverfault.com/a/663803/430884), it may come handy, but I'm not sure whether it's supported by `apk`.